# association names must be a Symbol Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello guys I am developing an application with 2 models in ROR
my routes.rb file

```
resources :questions do
       resources :answers
end
```

One of my model :

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to Question
end
```

Another model :

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, :dependent=>:destroy
end
```

and my show.html.erb file

```
<h1><%= @question.title %></h1>
<p><%= @question.details %></p>
<small><%= @question.created_at %></small>
<h1>Answers</h1>
<%= render @question.answers %>
<h2>Add an answer</h2>
<%= render "answers/form"%>
```

when I trigger show action I am getting following error:
association names must be a Symbol

Comment: An error message can't really be more clear than that one

Answer (score 3):

change this, question should be in symbol form

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

the error  `error: association names must be a Symbol` is already a hint to you.

for more see here -  [association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use capitalize any where in ur application that are strickly writted in ruby guides

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```